# Importing sql script and running it using node oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I have got query.sql file that I am importing using node's fs module and trying to run it using node oracledb module. But it is giving me the error of invalid or missing options

```
set echo off
set abc on

select * from table

set echo on
```

Comment: You're trying to use [SQL\*Plus `set` commands](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm) in another application; they are not SQL statements and will throw "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option". Are you able to pre-process the script file to remove them?

Comment: The driver executes SQL statements and PL/SQL blocks, but not scripts. Someone could write a module to parse scripts and execute them with the driver, but it's not trivial and I'm unaware of anyone having done it yet. Do you have to run the script or can you just execute the SQL and PL/SQL within it? Do you have to use Node.js or can you use another tool like SQLcl which works with scripts out of the box https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html?

Comment: Well, maybe not quite out-of-the-box, since you also need a Java SDK installed :)  If you don't have a JDK, it'll be a lot faster to [download SQL*Plus](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client.html)

Comment: @AlexPoole preprocess in what way and why do I have to remove them.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I have to use node js only using the node oracledb driver. Could you suggest me any other npm module that supports executing of scripts?

Comment: @ChristopherJones,  I have to run this script through the code.

Comment: You cannot run the script as it is; you at least need to strip out the non-SQL parts (the client-specific SQL\*Plus `set` commands etc.), but if the script contains multiple SQL statements (and/or PL/SQL blocks) then you will have to separate those out - which isn't trivial - and run those statements one by one. It's probably still easier to call out to SQL\*Plus.

Comment: It seems you didn't write this script, someone else did. However, they didn't write it in a way that it's executable by Node.js or the driver. So why do you have some constraint that you execute the script using Node.js? One of the following must happen: #1 You write a module that parses the script and makes it executable (I don't recommend this). #2 You get a clean script that would make it easier to execute in Node.js (I doubt you'll get this). #3 You use a tool designed to execute the type of script you were given (this make the most sense).

Comment: @DanMcGhan thank you for the suggestion . Could you also recommend me some language to use this with.

Comment: There are two free tools that I know of that you could use with the script as it is: #1 SQL*Plus - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/sqlplus-cloud.html and #2 SQLcl - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html SQL*Plus is a favorite among DBAs while developers would likely favor SQLcl.